# Чтение и запись данны из файла в javascript

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть html файл, мне нужно из него считать строку, и добавить её в другой html файл, который в это время открыт в браузере. После добавление браузер должен отобразить изменения в html документе, но не перезагружаясь.Добавить нужно в виде ТУТ ТЕКСТ блока. Вопрос, куда смотреть, и возможно ли это вообще? FileReader как я понял работает только с тэгом  и срабатывает на какое-то событие, плюс он не может считывать что-то в виде html

Comment: а где код? это node js  или  это все на клиенте?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко кода нет, так как я не знаю даже, как подойти. Нет, это сервер. Данные берутся не из пользоватеских файлов

Comment: тебе нужно с клиента запросить данные ,   нодой считать то что надо  и отправить браузеру обратно нужные данные. осталось только понять что нужно читать нодой - это уже интереснее - зачем данные хранить в html- может их лучше хранить в бд или в json?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко ну там лежит текст, я подумал, что можно оттуда будет брать то, что мне нужно, с помощью getElementById и пр. Поэтому используется html

Comment: ну, нода так не работает.   отдаваемые данные лучше формировать на сервере , и тексты и все сотальное хранить отдельно - если ты их переиспользуешь.